# API Gateway quotas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, quota

We need to have an endpoint to receive http POST requests and send them to SQS with both headers and payload. API Gateway with `REGIONAL` type and SQS integration works great and satisfies our needs. However, we are slightly worried about the limits of [600 requests per second](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#w410aac36c11b5) as it might not be enough for our case. Do we correctly understand that API Gateway HTTP API (that is not REST API with `REGIONAL` or `EDGE` types) can receive 10.000 requests per second, but in this case we would need to "build" our own integration to SQS (e.g. using lambdas)?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I believe there is a quota of 600 regional APIs (not request rate) per region. That mean, you can create 600 APIs, each of them with up to 10k requests per second. The quota 10k requests per second is, however, shared across these APIs, so if you have 100 APIs, each of them can receive can, in average, receive 1k requests per second. However, if 99 of them sit idle, the one API can get 10k requests per second.